# ADB push fails if softlinks are present during recursive copy

Tags: android, adb

I have many files in a directory. Few of them are softlinks.

When I copy individually, softlink copy works fine without any issues.

```
$ adb push .libs/libgsti.la /sdcard/temp/.libs/
121 KB/s (5196 bytes in 0.041s)
```

But when I try to copy all the files in a directory containing the softlink, it fails when trying to copy the softlink with error :

> Function not implemented

```
$ adb push .libs/ /sdcard/tmp/.libs/
...... (All success)
failed to copy '.libs/libgsti.la' to '/sdcard/temp/.libs/libgsti.la': Function not implemented
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Have you found any workarounds in the meantime?

Comment: I've filed a bug report to Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72366966

Comment: @DoDo Thanks for filing the bugreport. I cant recollect for sure what I did!

Comment: My current workaround is to first copy the folder to temporary dir with `cp -r` which follows the symlinks and then push the copy to the device. Not nice, but works.

Comment: That doesn't work